# How do I make rigid bodies on a spinning plate move accordingly?

Tags: unity

I have two 3D objects in my scene, a spinning plate (rotating flat disc) which has a `Mesh Collider`, and a `Rigid Body` cube.

The cube has gravity enabled, but when it lands on the plate it doesn't move along 'with' the plate, but just kinda lays on it as if the plate wasn't spinning.

The plate spins using the following code:

```
Update(){
    transform.Rotate(0, Time.DeltaTime * 64, 0, Space.Self);
}
```

I tried making the plate itself a `Rigid Body` (with gravity off of course), but it makes no difference.

I also read somewhere about adding `Torque` instead of rotating as I did above, but that had no effect.

I figured it was a lack of friction that was causing the issue, so I added a `Physic Material` to the plate (and also tried it on the cube), and bumped up the dynamic and static friction.... no luck.

How do I make the cube follow the movement of the plate (in other words, ride the plate)?

I expect that if the plate rotates fast enough that the box will start to slide outward.

Comment: It is not true that you can only apply torque to kinematic bodies, and it is also not true that a kinematic body cannot exert forces on dynamic bodies like the boxes. Can you show us your rigidbody attempt in detail? We may be able to spot what you got wrong.

Comment: You're probably right, I just set kinematic to true and the box does land on the plate.  Applying torque also seemed to cause the plate to spin regardless of whether kinematic was on or off. I have updated my question. Applying a physic material with friction on also did nothing. Although using bounce did work as my box did indeed bounce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform.rotate doesn't so much rotate the body but rather teleports it to its new position. If you want a rotating object to interact physically correct, give it a rigidbody and rotate it via the rigidbody.MoveRotation method.

If it still doesn't work, check the physics materials to make sure there is enough friction.